# symbology interpretation in the datasheet

Tags: datasheet

I am creating a footprint for QFN28 package and found the following symbols in the datasheet.

[image: symbols]

Immediately below, I found the following table of values.

[image: values]

**My question is**: What do these symbols mean? How should I interpret them?

Comment: What "value" of the pin? This is a mechanical drawing. It's telling you the size and shape of the pins.

Comment: Related: [What is the meaning of this drill notation on datasheet PCB drawing?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/193856/)